# what is the full phrase of the contraction zeal's

Tags: grammar, contractions

I saw the following below while I was playing the game name [Chrono Trigger](https://store.steampowered.com/app/613830/CHRONO_TRIGGER/)

> Zeal's advances stem from a new energy source.

What is the full phrase of the contraction word Zeal's in the following?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Zeal's** is not a contraction; it is a possessive form.

The advances of (or by) Zeal (apparently something in a computer game) stem from a new energy source.

The dog's left ear is black. (The left ear of the dog is black).

Mary's car is red (The car belonging to Mary is red).

Comment: In this case, I assume Zeal is a kingdom - specifically, the Kingdom of Zeal in the video game Chrono Trigger (what exactly that new energy source is turns out to be a rather major spoiler for the game).

Comment: I'm understanding, thank you. I took that following from the video game Chrono Trigger actually.